# Stack up views in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I'm actually a little bit confuse. I had to refactor some old code, and i've ended up with the place where hundreds of views which need to stack up on each other are just adding to `RelativeLayout` with

```
 parentView.addView(m_view, 0);
```

Which is kinda sad. So i wanted to rewrite it as a RecyclerView elements, but instantly faced problem of their order. I can't find any examples on how to do it, maybe i google it incorrect or smth. I've tried to write my own `LayoutManager`, but i couldn't find any obvious way to achieve my goal.

**Is there maybe another way? Or it's not that hard to order childs in `RecylcerView` like they are in `RelativeLayout`?**

As was suggested in comments, i've added an image to see how i want it to look [image]

As you can see views are lying on each other, that's what i want to achieve

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the desired result?

Comment: @Artjom check the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer you to use this library.

- [SwipeStack](https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack) : A simple, customizable and easy to use swipeable view stack for Android.

[image]

Comment: Yes, thx, i'm already using it from yesterday, but doesn't finished yet

Comment: I don't know, i would accept it i guess, if someone will face same problem in future